# Delete lines not match with the value. (PHP)

Tags: php, file, file-handling

Content of the text file (test.txt):

```
115.5.108.249 2015-03-01
118.110.6.87 2018-01-03
36.120.105.13 2018-04-06
```

I'm familiar with the following:

```
$fname = "test.txt";
$date  = date("Y-m-d");
$lines = file($fname);
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (!strstr($line, $date)) {
        $out .= $line;
    }
}

$f = fopen($fname, "w");
fwrite($f, $out);
fclose($f);
```

This command will only delete the line that contains the current server history and date ($date). I want this command to run in reverse. Line cleaner whose history (date) is old and no match with current server date (The server where PHP runs). I hope you understand what I mean. Please helpe me.

Comment: You missed `$lines = file($fname);` somewhere at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to remove `!` from condition to make it reverse:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (strstr($line, $date)) { //change this condition
        $out .= $line;
    }
}
```